# How is changing a field to readonly a breaking change

Tags: c#

I have a class library `Foo`, currently in version 1.0.0.

Another library `Foo.Extensions` of version 1.0.0, has `Foo` 1.0.0 as a dependency.

Both libraries try to adhere to semantic versioning, i.e. a program using `Foo.Extensions` 1.0.0, should be upgrade `Foo` to version 1.0.1 without breaking functionality of `Foo.Extensions`.

To avoid any breakage, I'm concerned about making updates to `Foo` in a source and binary compatibility way.

The [Breaking Change Rules](https://github.com/dotnet/corefx/blob/master/Documentation/coding-guidelines/breaking-change-rules.md#signatures) states that

> Adding `readonly` to a field

is disallowed.

When is this a breaking change for e.g.

```
public class Foo
{
    private int bar;
}
```

My best guess would be in some sort of reflection scenario, as I've experienced some (de)serializers to require properties to at least have a private setter.

How does this relates to removing a private setter from a property?

```
public class Foo2
{
    public int Bar2 { get; private set; }
}
```

Comment: If you made that change, what do you _think_ it might break? _Keep in mind the doc you liked to is for a framework - so they are concerned with ensuring that API changes don't break the callers to the API._

Comment: Adding to the previous comment, your example isnt the greatest, considering that `bar` isnt part of the public API of  your example class.

Comment: Also, given the quote you linked to was in the context of signatures (i.e. method signatures) you may consider updating the question to show an actual method signature. _I also strongly suspect that the context **implies** that the field is not `private` (since otherwise it wouldn't form part of the signature)._

Comment: If there's an `IncrementBar()` method in the Foo class that increments `bar`, that will not work anymore; ergo, Breaking Change.

Comment: @Yatin The only odd thing about explicitly calling that out (hence why Jonas' question is a reasonable one) is that the compiler will enforce that. Thus, it seems odd to explicitly mention it.

Comment: @mjwills, I agree, and even I couldn't think of another scenario where this change would be a breaking change.